# Удаление элементов из массива и нахождение их индексов

Tags: java, массивы

Доброго времени суток всем. Подскажите, как удалить из массива элементов два самых больших элемента и вывести их индексы.

Comment: Добрый вечер. По каким критериям Вы хотите определить самый большой элемент? Ну и покажите, как Вы пытались решить проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] times = {341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299, 343, 317, 265};
    searchTop(times);
}

private static void searchTop(int[] times) {
    int maxTimes = times[0]; //самое большое значение
    int secondTimes = 0;//самое большое значение -1
    int numberMax = 1;//порядковый номер в массиве самого большого значения
    int numberSecond = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < times.length - 1; i++) {
        if (maxTimes < times[i + 1]) {
            secondTimes = maxTimes;
            maxTimes = times[i + 1];
            numberMax = i + 1;
        }
        if (maxTimes != times[i + 1] && secondTimes < times[i + 1]) {
            secondTimes = times[i + 1];
            numberSecond = i + 1;
        }
    }
    times[numberMax] = 0;//удаляем
    times[numberSecond] = 0;
   //Выводим
    System.out.println("№" + numberMax + "   " + maxTimes + " is first max & № " + numberSecond + " " + secondTimes + " is second max");
}
```

Comment: хоть бы Java Convention соблюдали в своем коде, в частности, в названии методов